# Filter an Xml parsed into a php array

Tags: php, xml

Here's my problem, I have an Xml file generated by a rss flux.

I made it into a php array to get the datas easily.

The point is to filter the array with a tag name, an engine research in fact.

Here's my code for the moment :

```
<?php
function xml2array($contents, $get_attributes=1, $priority = 'tag') { 
if(!$contents) return array(); 

if(!function_exists('xml_parser_create')) { 
    //print "'xml_parser_create()' function not found!"; 
    return array(); 
} 

//Get the XML parser of PHP - PHP must have this module for the parser to work 
$parser = xml_parser_create(''); 
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); 
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0); 
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); 
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values); 
xml_parser_free($parser); 

if(!$xml_values) return;//Hmm... 

//Initializations 
$xml_array = array(); 
$parents = array(); 
$opened_tags = array(); 
$arr = array(); 

$current = &$xml_array; //Reference 

//Go through the tags. 
$repeated_tag_index = array();//Multiple tags with same name will be turned into an array 
foreach($xml_values as $data) { 
    if($data != $mot) {     
        unset($attributes,$value);//Remove existing values, or there will be trouble 

    //This command will extract these variables into the foreach scope 
    // tag(string), type(string), level(int), attributes(array). 
        extract($data);//We could use the array by itself, but this cooler. 

        $result = array(); 
        $attributes_data = array(); 

        if(isset($value)) { 
            if($priority == 'tag') $result = $value; 
            else $result['value'] = $value; //Put the value in a assoc array if we are in the 'Attribute' mode
            }
    } 

    //Set the attributes too. 
    if(isset($attributes) and $get_attributes) { 
        foreach($attributes as $attr => $val) { 
            if($priority == 'tag') $attributes_data[$attr] = $val; 
            else $result['attr'][$attr] = $val; //Set all the attributes in a array called 'attr' 
        } 
    } 

    //See tag status and do the needed. 
    if($type == "open") {//The starting of the tag '<tag>' 
        $parent[$level-1] = &$current; 
        if(!is_array($current) or (!in_array($tag, array_keys($current)))) { //Insert New tag 
            $current[$tag] = $result; 
            if($attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 

            $current = &$current[$tag]; 

        } else { //There was another element with the same tag name 

            if(isset($current[$tag][0])) {//If there is a 0th element it is already an array 
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result; 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; 
            } else {//This section will make the value an array if multiple tags with the same name appear together
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result);//This will combine the existing item and the new item together to make an array
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 2; 

                if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well
                    $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr']; 
                    unset($current[$tag.'_attr']); 
                } 

            } 
            $last_item_index = $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]-1; 
            $current = &$current[$tag][$last_item_index]; 
        } 

    } elseif($type == "complete") { //Tags that ends in 1 line '<tag />' 
        //See if the key is already taken. 
        if(!isset($current[$tag])) { //New Key 
            $current[$tag] = $result; 
            $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 
            if($priority == 'tag' and $attributes_data) $current[$tag. '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 

        } else { //If taken, put all things inside a list(array) 
            if(isset($current[$tag][0]) and is_array($current[$tag])) {//If it is already an array... 

                // ...push the new element into that array. 
                $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]] = $result; 

                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes and $attributes_data) { 
                    $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                } 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; 

            } else { //If it is not an array... 
                $current[$tag] = array($current[$tag],$result); //...Make it an array using using the existing value and the new value
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] = 1; 
                if($priority == 'tag' and $get_attributes) { 
                    if(isset($current[$tag.'_attr'])) { //The attribute of the last(0th) tag must be moved as well

                        $current[$tag]['0_attr'] = $current[$tag.'_attr']; 
                        unset($current[$tag.'_attr']); 
                    } 

                    if($attributes_data) { 
                        $current[$tag][$repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level] . '_attr'] = $attributes_data; 
                    } 
                } 
                $repeated_tag_index[$tag.'_'.$level]++; //0 and 1 index is already taken 
            } 
        } 

    } elseif($type == 'close') { //End of tag '</tag>' 
        $current = &$parent[$level-1]; 
    } 
} 

return($xml_array); 
}  
$contents = file_get_contents('magasin.xml');//Or however you what it
$result = xml2array($contents,0);
print_r($result);
?>
```

So I would want to filter it by a tag (example : Iris) which show every result with this word in it. Can anyone help me ?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

In fact I used a way much better idea, a curl on the flux and a new simplexmlelement :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and use XPath and SimpleXML.

You can search for nodes much more easily:

http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/09/30/xpath-in-simplexml/